# Tool for auto editing config files

Tags: awk, sed, vagrant

I'm using Vagrant to provision VM boxes for our dev team. Sometimes I need to change a port number or listening address of a service on the VM and preferably automagically.

Question:

I'm looking for a tool which can auto edit text/config files? I'm thinking as the following 'commands':

- Find line starting with `port=` and replace it with `port=5000`.
- Find line matching `bind 0.0.0.0` and comment the line.

Right now I'm testing `sed` and `awk`, but those are pain in the ass sometimes :)

Comment: Sometimes, maybe. But for the straightforward use cases you mention they should be relatively pain free. Plus there are plenty of `sed` and `awk` users here that would like nothing more than to bring you into the light should you get stuck on specific task and post your good-faith attempt to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I kinda got bored yesterday and wrote a simple [LineEdit script](https://github.com/ddofborg/lineedit) (GitHub). It's first version, not complete and I'm sure has typos, but might be interesting for someone to play around with.

```
usage: lineedit.py [-h] [-f {starts,regex,exact,ends}] [-n]
                   [-p {replace,above,below,end,begin,comment,delete}]
                   [-m MAX] [-y] [-v] [-l] [--create]
                   file sourceline [destline]

LineEdit: A tool to quickly automate config file editing.

positional arguments:
  file                  Source file: file path which should be edited (should
                        be a textfile).
  sourceline            Source line: line to search for using one of the
                        method described in -f option.
  destline              Destination line: the line which will be added or will
                        replace source line using methods described in -p
                        options. If `-p comment` is used, this string will be
                        the comment characher. (default: None)

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -f {starts,regex,exact,ends}
                        Find source position using one of the methods.
                        (default: exact)
  -n                    Add the source line to the file, if the source line is
                        not found. Use with `-p end` or `-p begin`. (default:
                        False)
  -p {replace,above,below,end,begin,comment,delete}
                        Destination position: At which position should the
                        destination line be added/replaces. (default: replace)
  -m MAX, --max MAX     Maximum number of matches. If more matches are found,
                        no changes will take place. (default: 1)
  -y                    Yes, make changes to the file. Otherwise only show
                        line numbers which will be changes. (default: False)
  -v                    Output more debug information. (default: False)
  -l, --long-diff       Show whole file with changes, useful if the source
                        file is long. (default: False)
  --create              Create the output file if source file does not exists.
                        Useful if you want to append something to a (new)
                        file. (default: False)

Exit codes are as follows: -1 = There was an error. 0 = Everything went as
intented. 1 = No match was found. Nothing is replaced.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '# port 
     /^port=/ c\
port=5000

     # bind
     s/.*bind 0\.0\.0\.0.*/#&/
     ' YourFile
```

- use redirection  `>` + temporary file (for all sed version) or inline `-i` with GNU sed for modify the content
- Explaination

  - `/^port=/ c\` line starting with *port=*
  - `/.../` is a pattern selection (filter) using a Regular Expression (Regex)
  - `^` is a regex meta char for *start of line*
  - `port=` is your selection
  - `c\` change the line by next line (each ending `\` mean to add next line also
- `s/.*bind 0\.0\.0\.0.*/#&/`

  - `s///` substitute first pattern by second one
  - `.*` every character (so here everythinhg of the line from the start until bind for the first and everything until the end for the second )
  - `bind` word `bind` followed by `0.0.0.0` but `.` is a metacharacter for any charcter so i escaped it for us it as litteral character (alternative is using a class pattern `[.]`)
  - `#&`  is replacing with a `#` followed by the found pattern with the meta character `&` (in our case, the whole line)

Comment: Thanks :) Probably using `sed` or `awk` is the most practical idea.